# 404 error not mapping with error page

Tags: java, spring, servlets, web.xml

I have configure web.xml as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <!-- Config here. -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringConfig</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringConfig</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath: SpringConfig.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>    

    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>

  </listener>

  <error-page>
    <exception-type>404</exception-type>
    <location>/404error.html</location>
   </error-page>

</web-app>
```

This is my simple 404error.html page located in WebContent folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
The Page You Are Looking For Is Not Available.
</body>
</html>
```

But I am not getting above custom page, can you guys tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It is working fine in my all applications.

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a typo error that you mentioned `htm` instead of `html` for servlet-mapping in your web.xml as mentioned here:

```
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
```

Try changing this to :

```
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

Comment: It is not typo mistake, I had use view resolver in spring configuration file to map .htm url to my .jsp

Answer (score 0):

Change `exception-type` to `exception-code`

```
<error-page>
    <exception-code>404</exception-code>
    <location>/404error.html</location>
</error-page>
```